# Why $injector:modulerr error when I run my test with karma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

What can cause this error?

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fooApp due to:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$stateProvider
            .state')
```

Edit post +++

```
inject(function ($injector) {
    MyService= $injector.get('MyService');
 });
```

MyService = undefined why ?

EDIT post ---

My service(Provider) :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooApp')
.factory('MyService', function () {

    var function1 = function function1(value) {
        return value;
    };

    return {
        function1: function1
    };
});
```

my test :

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: MyService', function () {
beforeEach(module('fooApp'));

var MyService;

beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function ($injector) {
        MyService= $injector.get('MyService');
    });
});

it('should ....', function(){
    expect(MyService.function1('....')).toEqual(...);
    .....
});
......
});
```

foo.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('foo', {
            url: '/foo',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/foo/foo.html',
                    controller: 'FooCtrl'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: 'components/footer/footer.html',
line 15:            controller: 'FooterCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
});
```

stacktrace :

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fooApp due to:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$stateProvider
            .state')
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/app/foo/foo.js:15
    at invoke (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182)
    at runInvokeQueue (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4088)
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4097
    at forEach (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
    at loadModules (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120)
    at createInjector (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4004)
    at workFn (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2339)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=fooApp&p1=TypeError%3A%20'undefined'%20is%20not%20a%20function%20(evaluating%20'%24stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.state')%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fauth.js%3Fb8f7bccdf2d8f57e6d6f0c810e0d1c6f0d3df707%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4182)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4088)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4097%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A323)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4120)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4004)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js%3Fb01a9cf8de7de4def103da067347cb07fe247c96%3A2339)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A1145%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2130%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2460%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2130%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2606%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2167
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4118
    at forEach (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
    at loadModules (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120)
    at createInjector (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4004)
    at workFn (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2339)
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('fooApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'pascalprecht.translate',
'restangular'
])
.........code........
```

karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
        'client/bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js',
        'client/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        'client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'client/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js',
        'client/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js',
        'client/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
        'client/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-cookie/angular-cookie.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js',
        'client/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-    partial.js',
        'client/app/app.js',
        'client/app/**/*.js',
        'client/components/**/*.js',
        'client/app/**/*.html',
        'client/components/**/*.html'
    ]
```

Bower.js :

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.7",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~4.0.5",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.1",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.6",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.11.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.5.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.5.2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "~0.8.*",
    "metisMenu": "~1.1.3",
    "restangular": "~1.4.0",
    "blueimp-md5": "1.1.0",
    "angular-cookie": "~4.0.6",
    "angular-datatables": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.9.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.8",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.8"
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with angular.mock.inject method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456231/issue-with-angular-mock-inject-method)