# Issue with angular.mock.inject method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I am using folloing jasmine test case

```
'use strict';

describe('companyService', function() {

    var $httpBackend, companyService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_ ,  _companyService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyService = _companyService_;
    }));

    it('should return a promise for getCompany function', function() {
       // expect(typeof companyService.getCompany('foobar').then).toBe('function');
    }); 

});
```

i am getting the following error . as you can see above . i am not doing anything inside **it** block .

```
    minErr/<@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
       loadModules/<@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4138:15
       forEach@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11
       loadModules@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4099:5
       createInjector@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:11
       workFn@C:/Users/userone/Documents/myAppPkg/myApp/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2425:44
irefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.251 secs / 0.008 secs)
```

I assume this issue comes because of the angular.mock.inject method i have been using . because the **execution does not** enter the following block

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_ , _companyService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyService = _companyService_;
    }));
```

Karma.conf.js file

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu May 21 2015 16:24:51 

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/app.js',
            'app/*.js',
            'app/**/*.js',
            'app/**/**/*.js',
            'app/company/CompanyService.js',
            'test/company/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


     // web server port
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 44555,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

can any one help me out with this . ?

Comment: Syntax looks correct. Have you setup the Karma config correctly to point the scripts? In particular the one containing companyService.

Comment: @WayneEllery thank you for your response . I have added the karma.conf.js file . Is there anyway to know that i have included all the dependencies in the karma.conf.js file . ?

Comment: I think you may be able to view the list in the console. Just make sure that they are set in files: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/files.html and when you run karma point it to the config file. Make sure it's using the config file

Answer (score 1):

You should update the "karma-chrome-launcher" and "karma-firefox-launcher" in  node_module.
This may be solve the issue.

**npm install karma-chrome-launcher**

**npm install karma-firefox-launcher**

If you think the issue because of **"angular.mock.inject  "**  then one can use **inject** function.

But I think your unit test script is not getting chance for loading and execution.So,this will not reason for above error.

Thanks.

Comment: i am using the latest launchers . Yes i have used and tried inject only . but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution for this problem. Turns out i have missed some dependencies in the karma.conf.js . When you missed dependencies , the $inject method does not get executed . What i did was , from the index.html , copied all the dependencies (from bower componants folder and node_modules folder) and put them in the karma.conf.js under files .

for example , i have copied all the file dependencies from index.html and put it under files

```
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

            'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.core.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.buttons.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.confirm.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.desktop.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.nonblock.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.callbacks.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.history.js',
            'bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.reference.js',

            'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
            'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',

            'js/fullcalendar.min.js',
            'js/daterangepicker.min.js',

            'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
            'bower_components/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js',

            'bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_no.js',
            'bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js',

            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',

            'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',

            'bower_components/angular-pnotify/src/angular-pnotify.js',

            'bower_components/angular-local-storage/angular-local-storage.js',

            'bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js',

            'bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js',

            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap-switch/dist/angular-bootstrap-switch.js',
            'bower_components/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js',

            'app/app.js',
            'app/**/*.js',
            'test/**/*Spec.js'
```