# Errors (forEach@, loadModules@, createInjector@, workFn@) when Testing $controller decoration

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have decorated a controller "originalCtrl" by decorating the $controller service:

```
//module declaration
angular.module('decorationModule', [
        'originalModule',
        'ExternalService'
    ])
    //decoration
    .decorator('$controller', function ($delegate, ExternalService) {
        return function () {
            //check when the OriginalCtrl is instantiated
            if (arguments[0] === 'OriginalCtrl') {
                return function () {
                    const ctrl = $delegate.apply($delegate, arguments)();
                    //memorize the original close function
                    const delegatedCloseFn = ctrl.closefn;
                    ctrl.close = function close() {
                        alert('bye bye before closing');
                        ExternalService.fn();
                        delegatedCloseFn();
                        alert('bye bye After closing');
                    };
                    return ctrl;
                }
            }
            else {
                return $delegate.apply($delegate, arguments);
            }
        }
    });
```

it is working well.

But, trying to make a Unit test on it:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('decorationModule', ($controller, $q, ExternalService) => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = () => {
        return $controller('OriginalCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    };
    spyOn(ExternalService, 'fn').and.returnValue();
}));

it('should call decorated close function', inject((ExternalService) => {
    //given
    const ctrl = createController();
    expect(ExternalService.fn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    //when
    ctrl.close();
    //then
    expect(ExternalService.fn).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

I got an error:

> forEach@/home/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:24
>       loadModules@/home/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:12
>       createInjector@/home/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:4470:30 
>       workFn@/home/.../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2954:60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with angular.mock.inject method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456231/issue-with-angular-mock-inject-method)

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines in my karma configuration file helped me to solve this error

```
files: [
  '../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
  '../www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
  '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  '../www/js/*.js',
  'test.js'
],
```

Here test.js is the file where I have written my test cases.
And try by replacing the line

```
angular.mock.module('decorationModule' ......
```

With this

```
module('decorationModule' ......
```

By the way I'm working with ionic so I have added ionic.bundle.js file and if this is not your case provide me configuration file to help you.
And make sure versions of angular.js and angular-mocks.js are same.
Hope it helps.